# Would it be appropriate to ask SO about how computers sort arrays of chinese characters (UTF-8)

Tags: support, questions, scope

I ask because I didn't have an actual problem regarding chinese character enumeration. I just happened to have this thought come to my mind and I'm eager to know it.

My question would be about sorting an array full of UTF-8 chinese characters. I know that in real life, there are several sorting methods, but in programming, it'd be interesting to know if there's a standard (maybe the UTF-8 character ID order? Pinyin order?) or the likes.

Comment: As formulated, I'm doubtful, it seems somewhat broad. If you could make it more specific, like how does programming language / implementation X compare and sort strings with Chinese, it could be reasonable.

Comment: It's too broad and open-ended as currently imagined. There are a variety of different sorting approaches for characters/strings, including numeric ordering (based on the numeric values of each code point) and lexicographic ordering (which would take into account natural language rules). If you were asking about a specific programming language, library, and/or function, then that might be on-topic.

Comment: As a native speaker I've personally used stroke count (though I write in simplified) and pinyin order. According to the top answer to [this Quora question](https://www.quora.com/How-does-alphabetical-order-or-sorting-order-work-in-Chinese), UTF-8 sorting is an incoherent mishmash, which makes me all the more curious how it actually does it (which would in fact be well-scoped for SO).

Comment: I would sort by 7'th bit in UTF-16 representation (why? just because I pull that from thin air)... How to sort array of anything is 110% opinion based - you probably have something else in mind as a question but as currently stated it makes no sense for any other language so would get closed as unclear... ?Wdehhilooorssttttuuwxyy

Comment: @Alexei Levenkov: The second paragraph of this meta question is clear. The asker is aware there are different ways to sort depending on your application, but is asking if there is some sort of canonical sort order (defined by UTF-8 or some other standard). If there *isn't* a canonical sort order, then *that* would be the answer. Nothing opinionated about that, unless you consider the Unicode spec to be the written opinion of the Unicode consortium, in which case everything code is or is based on the written opinion of someone.

Comment: Sorting is locale dependent. How locales are implemented is really down to the libraries used by a particular tool; databases usually have a *boatload* of options (look for [*collations*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Collation)). So without further context this would be too broad.

Comment: Here is a starting point: the [Unicode consortium’s FAQ on collation](http://unicode.org/faq/collation.html).